# issue with redux and typescript - doest not take in account my if statement

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

here are my types for the entity im working on (the timeline as TimeLineElement[]

```
export type ProJectTimelineElement = {
  project: Project;
};

export type MissionTimelineElement = {
  mission: EntityDataState;
};

export type AvailabilityTimelineElement = {
  availabilities: Availability[];
};

export type TimelineElementData = {
  project?: Project;
  mission?: EntityDataState;
  availabilities?: Availability[];
};

export type TimelineElement = {
  date: string;
  elements: TimelineElementData[];
};

export type EntityState = {
  data: EntityDataState[];
  isLoading: boolean;
  error: boolean;
  timeline: TimelineElement[];
};
```

and here my reducer where I have the type issue (saying that it is undefined even after a check if an if statement :

```
updateAvailabilities(state, action: PayloadAction<Availability>) {
      const timelineIndexToModify = state.timeline.findIndex(element => {
        const payloadDay = new Date(action.payload.start).getDate();
        const payloadMonth = new Date(action.payload.start).getMonth();
        const elementDay = new Date(element.date).getDate();
        const elementMonth = new Date(element.date).getMonth();
        return payloadDay === elementDay && payloadMonth === elementMonth;
      });

      if (state.timeline[timelineIndexToModify].elements.length === 0) {
        state.timeline[timelineIndexToModify].elements.push({
          availabilities: [{ ...action.payload }]
        });
      } else {
        const elementIndexToModify = state.timeline[
          timelineIndexToModify
        ].elements.findIndex(element => {
          if (element.availabilities) {
            return true;
          } else return false;
        });
        if (elementIndexToModify === -1) {
          state.timeline[timelineIndexToModify].elements.push({
            availabilities: [{ ...action.payload }]
          });
        } else if (
          state.timeline[timelineIndexToModify].elements[elementIndexToModify]
            .availabilities
        ) {
          const availabilityIndexToModify = state.timeline[
            timelineIndexToModify
          ].elements[elementIndexToModify].availabilities.findIndex(
            element => element.id === action.payload.id
          );
          state.timeline[timelineIndexToModify].elements[
            elementIndexToModify
          ].availabilities[availabilityIndexToModify] = action.payload;
        }
      }
    }
```

the issue is in the last `else if` statement
because this one can be undefined I check if it exist
but typescript does not care about that and say that it can be undefined
see the image

i do not know what to do, any help would be appreciated

[typescript error in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTg64.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue and questioned already. You should assign it to a variable before using like below.

```
const availabilities= state.timeline[timelineIndexToModify].elements[elementIndexToModify].availabilities

// Use this inside if statement
// Omitting...
else if (availabilities) {
      const availabilityIndexToModify = availabilities.findIndex(
        element => element.id === action.payload.id
      );
      availabilities[availabilityIndexToModify] = action.payload;
    }
```

[My previous question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73949826/why-assigning-an-array-item-to-variable-can-avoid-ts-possibly-null-error-but-di)